# Symfony2/Doctrine One-To-Many: Class integer does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I have a one-to-many self referencing entity.  Everything works fine as long as the parent value is set to null.  When I set the parent item to something actually in the list, I get the error:

> Class integer does not exist
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException

Here is the code for my entity:

```
<?php

namespace WorkRecorder\WorkBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="WorkRecorder\WorkBundle\Repository\WorkRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="strategyUsed")
 */
class StrategyUsed
{
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $sortOrder;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */ 
    protected $name;
        
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;    


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StrategyUsed", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StrategyUsed", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param text $description
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return text 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set sortOrder
     *
     * @param integer $sortOrder
     */    
     public function setSortOrder(\integer $sortOrder)
    {
        $this->sortOrder = $sortOrder;
    }

    /**
     * Get sortOrder
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getSortOrder()
    {
        return $this->sortOrder;
    }

    /**
     * Add children
     *
     * @param WorkRecorder\WorkBundle\Entity\StrategyUsed $children
     */
    public function addStrategyUsed(\WorkRecorder\WorkBundle\Entity\StrategyUsed $children)
    {
        $this->children[] = $children;
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param WorkRecorder\WorkBundle\Entity\StrategyUsed $parent
     */
    public function setParent(\WorkRecorder\WorkBundle\Entity\StrategyUsed $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return WorkRecorder\WorkBundle\Entity\StrategyUsed 
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't type hint on a scalar type (integer/string/boolean etc) in PHP. e.g.

```
public function setSortOrder(\integer $sortOrder)
```

Should be:

```
public function setSortOrder($sortOrder)
```

You can validate the type of the value within the method and perhaps throw an InvalidArgumentException if passed something that isn't an integer.

Comment: Outstanding!  Thank you so much.  I didn't notice it because Doctrine generated the setter for me.